# Mongodb Where condition with space in filename

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to apply where condition in mongodb using this following json file:
http://nicholasjohnson.com/mongo/datasets/stocks.json

I want to return all documents that have "EPS growth this year" less than "EPS growth next year".
I use the following command but the result is empty:

```
db.stock.find(
{$where: function()
{return("obj.EPS growth this year" < "obj.EPS growth next year")}
})
```

Maybe the problem is the space inside the filename. Do you have any suggestions to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe the problem is the space inside the filename.

Nope, it's not the space (also it's not a filename). You're comparing two literal strings and, since they're literals, they're the same for all documents. And this condition happens to be false, that's why you're getting no results.

You could try addressing the actual fields of the actual document

```js
db.stock.find(
{$where: function() {
 return this["EPS growth this year"] < this["EPS growth next year"]
}
})
```

Or, better yet, use `$expr` and aggregation framework: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#mongodb-query-op.-expr